# bilinear maps with respect to noncommutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Consider a *noncommutative* ring with unity $R$, three left $R$-modules $M,N,P$ and a map $f\colon\;M\times N\to P$ such that:

$
f(m+m',n)=f(m,n)+f(m',n)\\
f(m,n+n')=f(m,n)+f(m,n')\\
f(rm,n)=rf(m,n)=f(m,rn)
$

A map like this does exist: the null one. What about others? Can exist a non-null map satisfying those axioms? From the third point, given two scalars $r,s\in R$, it is evident that $(rs-sr)f(m,n)=0$ for all $m,n$ and this could be a problem given that $R$ is non-commutative.

Comment: This is one reason why this isn't a natural choice for defining bilinear maps over noncommutative rings. [Here is a discussion of the more natural choice](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1031255/29335)

Answer (score 4):

Such a map can exist, but not for every noncommutative ring. For example, no such map can exist over a division ring. This is because the annihilator of the left tensor product module is a nonzero left ideal, hence the left tensor product is always trivial in that case.

For an example where the map does exist, let $T$ be the tensor algebra over a field, and let $I$ be the two sided ideal generated by $rs-sr$. The quotient is the symmetric algebra $S$ over the field. Let $f:S\times S\to S$ be given by multiplication. Then this is a nonzero left bilinear map over $T$.

Comment: +1 very natural. The last paragraph is just a convenient illustration of a ring where the commutator ideal is proper, so (moppio89) if you have any other such examples in mind, they'll work too.

Comment: For example, the commutator ideal in the upper triangular matrix ring $T_2(F)$ is just the strictly upper triangular matrices. The quotient is $F\times F$, and that would work as another example.